# Android File.exists() need permission?

Tags: android, file, android-permissions

Do I need Android permission(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) for calling exists() method?
When I tested it, I can get true or false in internal storage without permission.

What if in External storage like sdcard?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No.

I tested，no matter `READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` granted or not, even user clicked the `never ask again` to refuse read/write permission. the `File.exists()` still can work properly.

tested on Android 8.1.0

Comment: It sounds like a bug, isn't it?

Comment: @Gqqnbig I agree, but I guess no bytes are being read or written  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It is indeed a bug. It's fixed. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138601438

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

see this > https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

In order to read or write files on the external storage, your app must acquire the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` system permissions.